# How to use next() in jQuery to select the next image in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML:

```
<div class="container"><img src="path" class="A" id="A" /></div>
<div class="container"><img src="path" class="A" id="B" /></div>
<div class="container"><img src="path" class="A" id="C" /></div>
<div class="container"><img src="path" class="A" id="D" /></div>
<div id="Holder"></div>//displays large image
<div id="next">Next</div>//is used to displays next image
<input type="hidden" id="image_holder" />
```

My jQuery:

```
 /******Place image in large holder********/
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i,a,h;
    h=$('#image_holder');
    i=$('img.A').prop('id');
    a="<img src='my path/" + i + ".jpg' class='C' />";
    $('#Holder').html(a); 
    h.val(i);
});
/*******Next Image*****************/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#next').on('click',function(){
        var ih,nxt, 
        ih=$('#image_holder').val()//id of the last image
        nxt=$('#' + ih).next('img.A').prop('id');
        //nxt=$('#' + ih).siblings().next('img.A').prop('id');I have also tried
        //nxt=$('#' + ih).parent().siblings().next('img.A').prop('id');I have also tried
        alert(nxt);
    });
});
```

All that the alert is giving me is `undefined`. I need the next image id that follows the first one.

When someone clicks on the image, it places the image in the `<div id="Holder">`. What I want is when the user clicks the next button, the next image in the flow is placed in the holder.

Can someone please take a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong or what I have not done yet? When I remove the `.prop('id')` I get `Object Object` in the alert box.

Comment: Try using `.attr()` for all places you are using `.prop()`, and try adding `console.log(nxt=$('#' + ih).next('img.A'))`

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte I have done this an still not working.

Comment: You don't need multiple `$(document).ready(function() {...});` wrappers. Put all your code in one.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method gets the immediate following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.

Because each of your images are individually wrapped in a `<div class="container">`, they have no immediate siblings and the call to `.next()` returns an empty set. When you then subsequently call `.prop()` (NOTE: you should use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to extract the ID), it returns undefined because it is operating on an empty set of elements.

To resolve this you can put all of your images in a single container.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="path" class="A" id="A" />
    <img src="path" class="A" id="B" />
    <img src="path" class="A" id="C" />
    <img src="path" class="A" id="D" />
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pAKCz/1/)**

Comment: I made the adjustments and still it is displaying undefine

Comment: @Bryan Did you try the demo at the bottom of my answer? When I click the next button it displays *B* in the alert.

Comment: I can see this, let me try my script again.

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` gets you the next sibling element, but your `img` elements are all only children. So you actually want to go up a level first. You were close with your third option, but you need to remember to go back down a level:

```
nxt=$('#' + ih).parent().next('.container').children("img").first().prop('id');
```

Comment: I am still getting undefine

Comment: I dont understand, I am doing everything that is there and it's still not working. I have everything to a **t** I can't understand what is happening. I must be retarded or something but I am not seeing the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the DOM a little more than you expected, simply:

```
next = $(this).closest('.container').next('.container').find('img');
```

Where `$(this)` is, of course, the starting point (replace by whatever selector you're actually using).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Answer (score -1):

Hope it may help, I spent a day looking for it... The thing is that the ('img') tag have to be filled in uppercase ('IMG'), otherwise, jquery won't recognize it. There it goes !